# Java - how to DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE, then enable EXIT_ON_CLOSE?

Tags: java, swing, window, listener

I've got a game where I'm trying to intercept a close event and return the user to the main menu instead.  I've got half of it figured out using `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` but then the problem is I can't return the regular functionality to the menu screen.

As you probably know, the problem is, the `windowClosing` method is apparently the last listener fired if `DO_NOTHING...` is the operation.

So, my question is, how can I return the `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` to the window, *after* `NOTHING` has been done?  I'd like to do it without any user input in the meantime. I can switch to another JFrame and handle it from there, but there's got to be a better way to do it.

Code sample:

```
WindowAdapter waReturnToMenu = new WindowAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent e) {
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        changeMenuState(0);
   }
};
```

Then, in change menu state:

```
public void changeMenuState(int i0) {
    //...screen returns to menu, then

    view.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not include this logic in your WindowListener since this will be called when closing is ever attempted? Your code sets the state of  a boolean variable to tell the WindowListener if you wish it to return the user to the program or close the program. In the WindowListener you would check the state of this boolean variable, and if the state is a certain value, exit the program via `System.exit(...)`.

(made into an answer)

e.g.,

```
// class field
private boolean canClose = false;

//....

WindowAdapter waReturnToMenu = new WindowAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent e) {
        if (canClose) {
           System.exit(0);
        } else {
           changeMenuState(0);
        }
   }
};
```

Then, in change menu state:

```
public void changeMenuState(int i0) {
    //...screen returns to menu, then

    canClose = true;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I like it thanks for the tip.  I'll have a dig at the code and come back.

Comment: I didn't actually use this method, but it's better than mine :) so I may implement it later.  Accepted, anyway, sorry for the long wait.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to add another window listener to capture the default closing event in changeMenuState.

So instead of

```
public void changeMenuState(int i0) {
    //...screen returns to menu, then

    view.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

I now have

```
public void changeMenuState(int i0) {
    //...screen returns to menu, then

    view.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
               view.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           }
    });
}
```

...which is then overridden later when the `waReturnToMenu` is added.

Comment: Coming back to this a few months later, I see that each time the window is opened/closed, a new event listener is added, which could lead to performance issues (I think).  So, this solution may be half right, and is probably half wrong.  However, it works too, so I'm leaving it in case it helps someone.